# Dax measure for monthly running total on weekly granularity

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have to visualize an accumulated monthly budget on a daily level.
Means a running total for the individual month on a daily basis.
The budget targets are provided in a table like this:

```
+------+------------+--------+
| Area | Year-Week  | Budget |
+------+------------+--------+
| A    | 2020-01    |     50 |
| A    | 2020-02    |     25 |
| A    | 2020-03    |     50 |
| A    | 2020-04    |     25 |
| B    | 2020-01    |     50 |
| B    | 2020-02    |     50 |
| B    | 2020-03    |     50 |
| B    | 2020-04    |     75 |
+------+------------+--------+
```

As you can see, the monthly budget for January is the sum of 2020-01 -  2020-04
The structure is provided in the calendar table. So I have the information on which week belongs to which month.

What I need to do is to create a dax measure that divides the weekly budget by the working days.
THe calendar has also the information of calendar days. For this purpose I have add this measure:

```
   Working Days =
    VAR vSelectedMonth = 
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Fiscal Month Number])
    RETURN
        CALCULATE ( 
            COUNTROWS ( 'Calendar' ),
            FILTER ( 
                'Calendar',
                'Calendar'[Fiscal Month Number] = vSelectedMonth
                  && 'Calendar'[IsWorkingDay] = 1
            )
        )
```

Now, how can I divide the weekly budget by the working days for the corresponding week and than to accumulate this information for the whole month?
Based on the provided information the result should be something like that:

```
+------+------------+----------------+
| Area |    Date    | Running Budget |
+------+------------+----------------+
| A    | 01.01.2020 |             10 |
| A    | 02.01.2020 |             20 |
| A    | 03.01.2020 |             30 |
| A    | 04.01.2020 |             40 |
| A    | 05.01.2020 |             50 |
| A    | 06.01.2020 |             50 |
| A    | 07.01.2020 |             50 |
| A    | 08.01.2020 |             55 |
+------+------------+----------------+
```

Of course, if the corresponding date is not a working day, that value from the day before should be shown.

I am grateful for every help!
Please let me know if you need further information.

Best Regards

Comment: Is there no Chancen?

Comment: Do you need further information?